# How to inject and use plugin in zend framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I've a controller  `Controller\Api\ProductController` for rest call and it's defined in `module.config.php`

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\Api\ProductController::class => function($container) {
            return new Controller\Api\ProductController(
                $container->get(\Commerce\Model\Product::class), $container->get(\Commerce\Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin::class)
            );
        }
    ]
]
```

In the above code you can see I'm injecting a  plugin class `\Commerce\Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin::class` which is defined in `module.config.php`

```
'controller_plugins' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'product' => Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin::class,
    ]
]
```

Now when I'm hitting the rest url it shows error message

> Unable to resolve service "Commerce\Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin" to a
>   factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

What I'm missing ?

Plugin code is

```
<?php

namespace Commerce\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class ProductPlugin extends AbstractPlugin
{
//....
}
```

Comment: in factories you have `Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin` and your namespace is `Commerce\Controller\Plugin` + class `ProductPlugin`

Comment: @Edwin I tried  `\Commerce\Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin::class` in factories too. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a Base controller and I had to inject plugins through dependencies 
based on the request.
Above configuration was fine. All I had to do is define my plugin in `service_manager` section.

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin::class => function($sm) {
           $dependencies = /////
            $model = new \Commerce\Model\Product($dependencies);
            return new Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin($model);
        },
        \Commerce\Model\Product::class =>  function($sm) {
            $dependencies = /////
            return new \Commerce\Model\Product($dependencies);
        }
    ],

],
```

Answer (score 2):

Controller plugins do not get injected to the controller.
Remove

```
$container->get(\Commerce\Controller\Plugin\ProductPlugin::class)
```

from the factory callback and also remove the 2nd parameter from the constructor of your ProductController

To use the plugin, just do:

```
$plugin = $this->plugin(Plugin\ProductPlugin::class);
```

or

```
// using the alias
$plugin = $this->product();
```

in your action controllers.

- https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc/plugins/
- [Controller plugin example](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Model_View_Controller/Controller_Plugins.html)

Comment: Thanks Jannes. Though I'm using a base controller and I had to inject plugin dynamically based on the request to the base controller.

Comment: Using plugins this way makes classes harder to test though.